# Client server communication using Distributed Object

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, gnustep

I am using Distributed Object for client server communication. I am storing clients object on the server for further communication between clients. when client terminate it will notify server about termination using `-(NSApplicationTerminateReply)applicationShouldTerminate:(NSApplication *)sender` method and server remove object of that client and notify other clients but if someone kill the client then how to notify server about termination?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See the section `Handling Connection Errors` in the `Distributed Objects Programming Topics`. The NSConnection objects will handle that case.